# Add click event on element still not in dom

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I have to add click event on a anchor element that can load later I know in javascript I can do like this.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'myDynamicallyAddedElementID'){
         //do something
    }
});
```

But I need to do In Typescript in angular and I am trying like this,

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        try {
        let id = e.target && (e.target as HTMLAnchorElement).id;
        console.log(id)
        if (id == 'lnkCheck') {
          alert('Hi');
        }
        } catch (error) {
          
        }
        

      })
```

But its not working, also How can I check if the target is an anchor tag

any help, highly appreciated,

**UPDATE**

the above code is working only issue was I was clicking on wrong place

Thanks

Comment: if you are sure that, only anchor tag click event should be handled, then why `event` on document ?

Instead you can have a global listener on `anchor`

Comment: I will put other conditions there as well, but this basic is still not working

Comment: I need to bind click event on anchor and h5 element with certian ids, but these two elements appear late in dom

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that element will be in the DOM with given id then this thing can be implemented with the help of AfterViewInit interface in the component something like this.

```
  import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
     
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  
      constructor() {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          try {
            let id = e.target && (e.target as HTMLAnchorElement).id;
            console.log(id);
            if (id == 'lnkCheck') {
              alert('Hi');
            }
          } catch (error) {}
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: the element will be inserted from external file on the page

Comment: try this once and let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target instanceof HTMLElement) {
        if (target.tagName === 'A' && target.id === 'lnkCheck') {
            alert('Hi');
        }
    }
})
```

Is this what you want?